# Mobile Connect Keyword Scenario

Tags: marketing-cloud

I have created Outbound SMS and selected next keyword in outbound the same keyword used in text response but i am unable to receive the text response sms.

Can any one help me out how to setup text response SMS in mobile connect using the keywords.

Answer (score 0):

To create the text response SMS, you need to click create message and select text response template.

Once it is done, add a name, message content and select shortcode.
Once you have selected shortcode, the saved keyword list shows up. You can select anyone or create a new keyword for the shortcode.

Then save and activate the message.

This should work. Let me know if you face any other issue.